# Space between td classes in HTML not working

Tags: html, html-table

I want to put every dropdown under the th title. 
What are my options? 

My code is below:

```css
tr {
  float: left
}

table {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<table id="CustomerTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No of Puffs </th>
      <th>No Per Day </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td class="dropdown">
      <form action="" name="FILTER">
        <select name="filter_for_No_of_Puffs">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </td>

    <td class="dropdown">
      <form action="" name="FILTER">
        <span style="display:inline-block; width: 30px;">
            <select name="filter_for_No_Per_Day" >
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
          </span>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/unyswphc/33/

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**. Don't host it only on an external site. Don't mention it only in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css was causing the problem.

`float: left` on all `<td>` tags was causing the issue and moving all content to the left irrespective of the table layout.
You have also missed `<tr>` tags in your `<tbody>`

P.S. Not sure if the table `width of 600px` is needed for two columns. So basically removing all your css will fix it.

```html
<body> 

<table id="CustomerTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No of Puffs </th>
            <th>No Per Day </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <tr>
             <td class="dropdown">
                 <form action="" name="FILTER">
                     <select name="filter_for_No_of_Puffs" >
                         <option value="0">0</option>
                         <option value="1">1</option>
                         <option value="2">2</option>
                         <option value="3">3</option>
                         <option value="4">4</option>
                          <option value="5">5</option>
                           <option value="6">6</option>
                           <option value="7">7</option>
                           <option value="8">8</option>
                           <option value="9">9</option>
                           <option value="10">10</option>
                     </select>
                 </form>
             </td>
             
             <td class="dropdown">
                 <form action="" name="FILTER">
                 <span style="display:inline-block; width: 30px;">
                     <select name="filter_for_No_Per_Day" >
                         <option value="0">0</option>
                         <option value="1">1</option>
                         <option value="2">2</option>
                         <option value="3">3</option>
                         <option value="4">4</option>
                          <option value="5">5</option>
                           <option value="6">6</option>
                           <option value="7">7</option>
                           <option value="8">8</option>
                           <option value="9">9</option>
                           <option value="10">10</option>
                     </select>
                     </span>
                 </form>
             </td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```